# dynamic_cast understanding

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, dynamic-cast

I have recently started dynamic_cast and static_cast. I did kind-of understand what was happening in static_cast but not in dynamic_cast. The most I know is that static_cast can be used to convert data types and does not check on compile-time but dynamic_cast does. Also I have written the a code using dynamic cast but I am not sure how they are related.
Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base{
public:
    virtual void setting(){
        cout << "Hello, I am a function from the base class" << endl;
    }
    virtual void say(){
        cout << "Base class says hi" << endl;
    }
};

class Child:public Base{
public:
    void setting(){
        cout << "Hello, I am a function from the child class" << endl;
    }
    void say(){
        cout << "Child class says hi" << endl;
    }
};

class Child2:public Base{
public:
    void setting(){
        cout << "Hello, I am a function from the child2 class" << endl;
    }
    void say(){
        cout << "Child class says Wazuppppp" << endl;
    }
};
void start(Base* bp){ //here is where I get confused
    Child* it_is_Child= dynamic_cast<Child*>(bp);
    if(it_is_Child){
        it_is_Child->say();
        it_is_Child->setting();
    }
    Child2* it_is_child2= dynamic_cast<Child2*>(bp);
    if(it_is_child2){ //then
        it_is_child2->say();
        it_is_child2->setting();
    }
};

int main(){
    Child cp1;
    Child2 cp2;
    start(&cp2);
    cout << endl;
    start(&cp1);
    system("pause");


    return 0;
 }
```

The confusion is that how are Child cp1 and Child2 cp2 are related to start function and how do they work. Also how does the compiler decides which one to pick.

Comment: You have it backwards. `static_cast` does compile-time checks, whereas `dynamic_cast` does the casting at runtime and gives a runtime error if the types are incompatible (like casting to the wrong derived class).

Answer (score 3):

`static_cast` will generate an error during compilation, if the associated classes are not related (where one is inherited from the other, or both are inherited from a common ancestor).

`dynamic_cast` will return a null pointer during runtime, if the conversion-class is not the exact class of the converted object.

In order for `dynamic_cast` to work, the conversion-class must declare at least one virtual function. This is because `dynamic_cast` uses the V-Table pointer of the converted object, and an object has a V-Table pointer only when its class declares virtual functions.

For example, the **behind the scene** of `Child* it_is_Child = dynamic_cast<Child*>(bp)` is:

```
if (bp->__vfptr == Child::vftable)
    return (Child*)bp;
return nullptr;
```

Please note that on some compilers you also need to enable RTTI in the project settings.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the compiler who decide which one. Using [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information), the compiler add inside the `Child`'s object some extra information (another implicit attribute) which records the actual class of the object. This extra information can be retrieved using `typeid`. Then for the call

```
Child* child = dynamic_cast<Child*>(bp);
```

the compiler generate some instructions that, thanks to this information, **at run time**, decide to return a pointer to the actual object or `NULL` if the class is not the correct one. Something like

```
if (typeid(*bp) == typeid(Child))
    child = reinterpret_cast<Child*>(bp)
else
    child = NULL;
```

**Note:** I'm over simplifying here. Actually `dynamic_cast` does something more complicated going down the full lattice of super class.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (typeid(*bp)`

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you would get exactly the same result if you were not using `dynamic_cast` (and in fact, this is what you are typically doing when you have objects that inherit from a baseclass). In other words:

```
void start(Base* bp){ //here is where I get confused
   bp->say();
   bp->setting();
};
```

would call the correct `say` and `setting`. (It will of course, in this case, also output from `base`, if you called it with a `base` object).

It would be much more interesting to have a case where `child2`, for example, has a different set of functionality than the other classes.

So, if we do:

```
class Child2:public Base{
public:
    void setting(){
        cout << "Hello, I am a function from the child2 class" << endl;
    }
    void say(){
        cout << "Child class says Wazuppppp" << endl;
    }
    void special() {
        cout << "Special function called" << endl;
    }
};
```

Now, if we do this, the function `special` is not available in `base`, but we can do:

```
 Child2 *it_is_child2 = dynamic_cast<Child2*>(bp);

 if (it_is_child2)
 {
     it_is_child2->special();
 }
```

The way `dynamic_cast` works is that the compiler generates code that, at runtime, "looks" at the input and determines if it is "the right type" (that is, that the class is related in the correct way to the class you are casting to). Typically, for ease, it does this by looking at the objects vtable, because classes that have the same base-class have vtables that can be matched. In some implementations, RTTI (Run-time Type Information) is used instead, but most implementations use the "vtable" method.

In general, when using inheritance, `dynamic_cast` (and clearly other casts between types) should be uses sparingly (and "always" with a check of the result).

Comment: Are you sure about "The way dynamic_cast works is that the ***compiler*** ..."?

Comment: The compiler generates code to compare the vtables, yes. Of course, the compiler isn't executing the code, the processor is... Being rather pedantic, aren't you?

Comment: You may have gotten me wrong here. Sorry if I offended you. What I was trying to find out is; is this check actually done during the compilation phase or is it done during the runtime of the resulting binary? Your comment suggests the latter but it still is unclear for me when reading your answer.

Comment: It happens at runtime. But it's a fairly simple operation. I have reworded a bit...